# Alternate method to stack two text rows on single line

Tags: html, css, forms

I have searched Stack Overflow for all search terms I am familiar with and have been successful creating a single row User Name/Password/Submit solution WITH two-stacked rows in-line showing an opportunity to "Remember Me" (checkbox) and a "Forgot Password?".

[image: This is what I am attempting to accomplish:]

The code I used to build this uses a Table structure and I am wondering if this is the best method given all the HTML5 and CSS enhancements (that I may not be familiar with). Is there a better (or more modern) approach to this that would be recommended to ensure strong browser support? Here is the code I've used thus far:

```html
<input type="email" name="email_address" id="email_address" tabindex="1" placeholder="Enter your EMAIL address">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Enter your PASSWORD">
<table style="display:inline-table;">
  <tr>
    <td  style="line-height:0.5; padding-top:0;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me">
      <label style="color:#fff; font-size:70%;" for="remember_me"> Remember Me</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  style="line-height:0.5">
      <label style="color:#fff; font-size:70%;" for="remember_me">Forgot Password?</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="3" value="Login" onClick="Login();">
```

Comment: @Mister Jojo: Thank you for editing the format of the code displayed. I used the 'show code' feature of the SO question editor and it formatted it in an odd way. Your edits help. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Mister Jojo: Great resource. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better to use flexbox box its less confusable

```html
<div style="background-color:#3f0;width:100%;display:flex;gap:8px"><!--flex added and gap-->
   <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email_address" tabindex="1" placeholder="Enter your EMAIL address">
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Enter your PASSWORD">
   <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"><!--flex added-->
   
      <div style="display:flex;align-items:center"><!--flex added-->
         <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me">
         <label style="color:#000; font-size:70%;" for="remember_me"> Remember Me</label>
      </div>
      
      <label style="color:#000; font-size:70%;" for="remember_me">Forgot Password?</label>
      
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="3" value="Login" onClick="Login();">
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate this response because it mirrors my original code while still offering a much more robust solution. Learning is enhanced when I can see the changes made. This is what makes Stack Overflow shine! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit you did that in a pretty odd way in my opinon. Here's how I would do it using Flexbox instead of a table.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#remember-password p {
  color:white;
  margin: 0;
}

#remember-password div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="email"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="password"/>
  <div id="remember-password">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <p>Remember Me</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Forgot Password ?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Login</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I see now that my original code would be "a pretty odd way" but it was all I knew how to do (after many SO searches) at the time I posted my question. I learn by trial and error so with your (and others) input I grow. Thanks for offering a solution!

Comment: We're here for that ! I was happy to help you @ND_Coder :) You should look in details at [Flexbox propertys](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as it's so usefull, personnally, I use it all the time ^^